# Best way to authenticate/authorize blog used only by the creator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication

I'm making a simple blog in which I will be the sole poster, and would like to make a simple but secure system of authentication/authorization for posting blog entries.
In this case, authentication and authorization will be the same, and I'm not sure if it's necessary to have a separate authentication model.

It seems to me the simplest way would be to just include my password in the url to my "new_post" page, by routing the following way in **routes.rb**

```
match '/my_password_here, to: 'Post#new'
```

Is this somehow a bad idea? If so please let me know why.

I'm still new to programming, and am learning the ropes on security-related issues. While I don't plan to be actively targeted by anyone, I'd imagine getting one's blog hacked is bad for business.

Thanks in advance for your input!

Edit: to clarify, I currently have just one model, `Post.rb`, and two controllers `posts_controller.rb` and `static_pages_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a (very) bad idea, because everyone can see your password by looking at the URL. Besides it will be in the browser's history. I recommend using [HTTP basic authentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "my_username", :password => "my_password", :except => [:index, :show]
end
```

Comment: haha, that's so easy. Thanks @Mischa for your suggestion. By the way, what do you mean by "everyone can see your password by looking at the URL"? How would they see the url?

Comment: You're welcome. They can see the URL by looking over your shoulder or by looking at the browser history.

Comment: ok, i see. Good to know I'll still have the option of hanging out among the hipsters at starbucks ;)